# what is the best way to save tuples in python

Tags: python

I have a function which returns a tuple which includes numbers, strings and arrays.For example, `(1, 2, 3, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], ['a','b','c'])`. I need to run my function 100 times and save all the results. I'm thinking of save each result as a text file.  So I can have 100 *.txt fils like this:

```
my number1: 1
my number2: 2
my number3: 3
My array:   [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
My Names:   ['a','b','c']
```

How to write the python code?

Is there better way to save the results for easy data re-visit in future?

Comment: Take a look at the python "pickle" package

Comment: or if everything is serializable, try `json` module

Comment: Thanks guys, But I want it to be saved as *.txt file. So I can just click on the file to CHECK it and read it using other language. With picle or json, we still need to write code to read it, isn't it? ----I'm probably like Matlab too much. Don't we have something similar like Matlab cells that can store all my results?

Answer (score 27):

yes, you can [`import pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and use `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()` to read and write to a file.

Here is how you would write it to a file:

```
data = (1, 2, 3, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], ['a','b','c'])
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

To read it back in:

```
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
     data = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: he wrote 'is there [a] better way', so I assume he is open to suggestions

Comment: "*easy data re-visit in future*": this could only be read by `pickle`.

Comment: `open('data.pickle', 'r')` should be `open('data.pickle', 'rb')`. Because if you are writing it to a binary file you should read it back from a binary file. Otherwise you are gonna get an encoding error

Comment: Good catch. fixed!

Answer (score 5):

If you want easy data revisit across-language, you can use JSON.

```
import json
data = (1, 2, 3, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], ['a','b','c'])
#save your data to a json file
with open('data01.json', 'w') as fjson:
    json.dump(data, fjson)

#json file can easily be read using other languages as well
with open('data01.json', 'r') as fjson:
    revis_data = json.load(fjson)
```

**Note:** The `revis_data` will be converted to a list and won't be a tuple anymore. If you want it to remain a tuple after reloading, just do `tuple(revis_data)`